# 1.9 from Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

[image]

Hello! This is from Rudin's RCA. During my reading 1.9 I have couple question:

$1)$ Why $(a)$ follows from Theorem 1.8 with $\Phi(z)=z$? If we put $\Phi(z)=z$ then $\Phi(u(x),v(x))=(u(x),v(x))$ but it's not $u(x)+iv(x)$. This moments confuses me.

$2)$ Why $g(z)=\operatorname{Re}z$ and $g(z)=|z|$ are continuous? How to prove it in topological language?

I would be very thankful for any answer.

Comment: For (2): how did you define the topology on $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, I begin read this book couple days ago so I'm not good at these topics. So I can't answer to your question. May be you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) He actually means $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, (x,y) \mapsto x+iy$. $\Phi$ is continuous as it is a linear map, then you can apply theorem 1.8.

2.) $Re$ is linear and hence continuous. The absolute value is lipschitz continuous by reverse triangle inequality and hence continuous.

Comment: $\Bbb R$-linear, I guess.

Comment: I guess that continuity have to prove by using open sets. Am I right?

Comment: @RFZ it is a general fact that (in finite dimension) all ($\mathbb{R}$-) linear maps between normed $\mathbb{R}$ vector spaces are continuous. However, in our case you can do everything by hand if you want to. It is easy to compute $\vert \Phi(x,y)\vert = \vert (x,y) \vert$ then the linearity gives you that $\Phi$ is lipschitz and hence continuous. For $Re$ one notes $\vert Re(z) \vert \leq \vert z \vert$ and by linearity you get again that it is lipschitz and therefore continuous.

Comment: But we are in topological spaces and we must show that pre-image of open set is always open. This is definition of continuity between topological spaces from Rudin.

Comment: But this are normed vector spaces as well. Then the definiton of continuity in terms of open set and in terms of $\epsilon-\delta$ coincide.

Comment: Maybe you mean metric spaces?

Comment: A normed space is a special case of a metric space.

Comment: I read your answer with big attention! May I ask the following questions: 1)   As you wrote Rudin actually means $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{C}$ defining it by $\Phi(x,y)=x+iy$. But since $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are metric spaces then definition of continuiuty in the language of open set and $\epsilon-\delta$ language are the same. But in $\epsilon-\delta$ language it's easy to prove that $\Phi, g(z)=\operatorname{Re}z, g(z)=\operatorname{Im}z, g(z)=|z|$ are continuous.
Am I right?

Comment: Precisely. You can even prove lipschitz continuity (which doesn't even make sense in the case of topological spaces).